# On difference of two sums of two squares plus difference of two cubes

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there a way to show that every integer $n$ can be represented by
$(a^3+b^2+c^2)-(d^3+e^2+f^2)$
Where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are all integers?

Comment: The real question is though- can it?

Comment: Please, show you have worked on the question. Instead, if you are awaiting all from you, the question will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, every integer can be expressed as $$ b^2 + c^2 - d^3  $$

This was a problem Kap and Noam Elkies gave to the MAA Monthly, Problems and Solutions column. It appeared in January 1995, Volume 102, number 1, page 70. The answers appeared in June-July 1997, Volume 104, number 6, page 574.

[image]

However, [not every number can be expressed as $ b^2 + c^2 - d^9  $](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/papers/Experimental_1995.pdf)

Much later, we found that not every integer can be expressed as
$$   4  x^2 + 2  xy + 7 y^2 - z^3 $$

I sent that one into the Monthly, the question appeared in December 2010. The single answer, by Robin Chapman, appeared in December 2012, volume 119, number 10, pages 884-885

For the curious, see the more difficult https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12486/integers-not-represented-by-2-x2-x-y-3-y2-z3-z

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every integer $k$ is of this form. This is trivial, because we may take $a=d$ and some of the $b,c,e,f$ equal to zero.
Every $k$ is either of the form $2n+1$ or $2n$.
We have
\begin{align*}
2n+1 & = (n+1)^2-n^2+0^2 \\
2n & =(n+1)^2-n^2-1^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I have found that every integer $n$ can be represented by
$(a^2+b^2)-(c^2+d^2)$
Because
$$n=((\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2})^2 + (\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{2})^2)-\left((\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{2}+1)^2 + (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2\right)$$
So, I am just wondering if there is at least an expression which suits the question i asked.

Comment: Please, have a look at the order of the brackets again and you will see the equation is actually correct. I think you mistakenly thought I meant $n=a^2+b^2-c^2+d^2$ which is not but $n=a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$.

Comment: I think the first term is equal to 1, don't you agree?

Comment: Yes, now I have seen it - I am sorry. But you can use a simpler formula, namely just $2n=(n+1)^2-n^2-1$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am curious to know if there are expressions which satisfy $a,b,c,d,e,f$ in my original question.

Comment: Yes, of course there are. You have just given such an expression with $a=d=0$. My answer is even easier with, say, $a=b=d=0$. If you wish, your answer gives such an expression also for nonzero $a,d$ with $a^3=d^3$. So you **don't need** $a$ and $d$, right?

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks a lot.